# Magento set_include_path() 

Tags: php, magento-1.6

The server admin is preventing magento " set_include_path" to be executed;
the admin insisted not to enable this function !
is there any way to solve that? ex: replace this line with a static value ?

That leads to the following errors:

```
Warning: set_include_path() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/bluerose/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 48

Warning: include_once(Mage/Core/functions.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/bluerose/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 49

Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Mage/Core/functions.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/bluerose/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 49

Warning: include_once(Varien/Autoload.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/bluerose/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 50

Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Varien/Autoload.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/bluerose/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 50

Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Autoload' not found in /home/bluerose/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 53
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Change the host is one alternative?

Comment: Request a version of the Magento 1.6 software that does not require that function call. Please contact the software vendor for that. Technically you should be able to enter absolute paths for every file that is included, so you also should be able to change the code for each system you want to use the software on.

Comment: Change host. You can't use Magento without it, even in the newest versions. Its a trivial function. All codepools are added to this include path stack for later checking for extends on core from within your local codepool via the autoloader. Absolute paths is a no go, changing code for this also prevents you from upgrading to newer versions when needed.